# Data structure to model a directory as a queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a requirement to create a file based Queue using a files directory (windows / unix).

The File based queue must allow clients to **add** a file to the bottom of the queue, and **remove** the first file of the queue.

What is the best **data structure** to use?

Comment: What do you think it could be?

Comment: You could use nested directories, and use `mkdir` to `add` and `mv`+ `rm` to remove

Comment: What kind of queue? Like a JMS queue? A [`java.util.Queue<java.io.File>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)? Must it be concurrent? Transactional? Your question is way too broad and helps us in no way to help you. Clarify your requirements and either edit this question or close it and make a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like to get back to you on this question I have answered myself.

The way I have implemented the solution as a File Based Queue (in windows) is to use the existing File directory structure and naming each file based on the System.milliseconds() and sorted numerically. This simulates the a queue maintaining the FIFO order.

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for specifically or if you are exclusively using Java, but it sounds like an ArrayList, or some variation of a List object could be useful to you as it allows easily adding and removing objects while still treating the group of data like an indexed array.

Comment: F.Y.I. There is an interface `java.util.Queue`.

Comment: I assume he wants to make something from scratch.